# Indexing issue in postgres

Tags: postgresql

It is impossible to speed up the database due to indexing.

I create a table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS coordinate( Id serial primary key,
                                   Lat DECIMAL(9,6),
                                   Lon DECIMAL(9,6));
```

After that I add indexing:

```
CREATE INDEX indeLat ON coordinate(Lat);
CREATE INDEX indeLon ON coordinate(Lon);
```

Then the table is filled in:

```
INSERT INTO coordinate (Lat, Lon) VALUES(48.685444, 44.474254);
```

Fill in 100k random coordinates.

Now I need to return all coordinates that are included in a radius of N km from a given coordinate.

```
SELECT id, Lat, Lon
FROM coordinate
WHERE acos(sin(radians(48.704578))*sin(radians(Lat)) + cos(radians(48.704578))*cos(radians(Lat))*cos(radians(Lon)-radians(44.507112))) * 6371 < 50;
```

The test execution time is approximately 0.2 seconds, and if you do not do **CREATE INDEX**, the time does not change. I suspect that there is an error in the request, maybe you need to rebuild it somehow?

*I'm sorry for my english*

Answer (score 1):

An index can only be used if the indexed expression is *exactly* what you have on the non-constant side of the operator. That is obviously not the case here.

For operations like this, you need to use the PostGIS extension. Then you can define a table like:

```
CREATE TABLE coordinate (
   id bigint GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
   p geography NOT NULL
);
```

and query like this:

```
SELECT id, p
FROM coordinate
WHERE ST_DWithin(p, 'POINT(48.704578 44.507112)'::geography, 50);
```

This index would speed up the query:

```
CREATE INDEX ON coordinate USING gist (p);
```